# OpenCV 3.0.0 FaceDetect Sample fails

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to get OpenCV running i am using the following 
[sample code](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)

I get the following Error line displayed:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp, line 1580
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1580: error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale
]
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(CascadeClassifier.java:176)
    at org.maxbit.opencv.samples.DetectFaceDemo.run(SampleB.java:29)
    at org.maxbit.opencv.samples.SampleB.main(SampleB.java:51)
```

Can any body tell me what that error means or how to debug this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I also faced the problem. The problem is in the .getPath() return an absolute path of the format.

Eg: "/C:/Users/projects/FaceDetection/bin/com/face/detection/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml".

So change the code like this.

```
CascadeClassifier faceDecetor = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetection.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1));
```

Comment: this should be the answer if you are using opecv 3.0.0

Comment: this should be the answer when using opencv 3

Answer (score 7):

This happens usually for two reasons.

1. Cascade classifier file `lbpcascade_frontalface.xml` not present at specified path.
2. Cascade classifier file is corrupted.

To get an error message instead of exception during runtime, try code sample as below. The `CascadeClassifier` [constructor](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp#L1536) is silent, if it cannot load the cascade classifier XML. The onus is on the developer to call the `empty()` method and check if classifier is loaded correctly

```
CascadeClassifier cascade = new CascadeClassifier( CASCADE_CLASSIFIER_PATH );
if ( cascade.empty() ) {
    //handler error here
}
```

Exception you got is from OpenCV native code assertion [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp#L1587).

Comment: Thanks that is better i miss spelled the path to the xml :S but now i have the problem that it fails on this line: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp#L3961

Comment: @maxbit89 Sorry. I couldn't help that. Separate question with more details might help.

Comment: here is the new question hope this helps :S http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346517/open-cv-3-0-0-face-detection-detectmultiscale-fails

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same error running on a Windows box. This sample runs on linux but not Windows.

The problem is in the `.getPath()` call after `getResource()` for both the xml file and the image.

The problem is that the `URL.getPath()` and the `URL.getFile()` both return an absolute path of the format "/c:/...".

The OpenCV routines choke on this it must be "c:/..." (no leading '/'). This seems like a bug in the early part of version 3.0.0?

I hope this helps, OpenCV for Java seems like a great tool ... but it is a bit frustrating when the examples don't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the latest openCV it doesn't work when you have spaces in your path so do this:

```
String s =CameraPanel.class.getResource("lbpcascade_frontalface.xml").getPath().substring(1);
String[] split = s.split("%20");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < split.length-1; i++) {
    stringBuilder.append(split[i]+" ");
}
stringBuilder.append(split[split.length-1]);
faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue: On windows, OpenCV chokes on both the prepended '\' and any whitespace in the path, as both Imad and Aung have noted. My solution is a bit shorter than Imad's:

Change this:

```
CascadeClassifier faceDecetor = new CascadeClassifier(
     getClass().class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
```

To this:

```
CascadeClassifier faceDecetor = new CascadeClassifier(
     getClass().class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1).replaceAll("%20", " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the simplest solution was:

```
private void checkboxSelection(String classifierPath) {
    // load the classifier(s)
    faceCascade.load(classifierPath);
    // Did it work?
    if (faceCascade.empty()) {
        // Try the full path
        String resource = getClass().getResource(classifierPath).getPath();
        // Discard leading / if present.
        if ( resource.startsWith("/")) {
            resource = resource.substring(1);
        }
        faceCascade.load(resource);
    }
    // now the video capture can start
    cameraButton.setDisable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using openCv 3.4.1 
I think there's a bug in CascadeClassifier initializer. 
In order to get rid of this error, I must call "load" once again. Hope this solution could help.

```
cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
cascadeClassifier.load(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced problem on Mac (OSX) Java.

```
    CameraFrame.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1) 
returned "Users/username/Desktop/JavaProjects/Camera/bin/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml".
```

whereas path should start with `"/"` therefore I appended `"/"`.

```
    face = new CascadeClassifier("/" + 
CameraFrame.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1));
```

It works OK now :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as well. It is just because the path you gave for 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml' might be incorrect of not proper. just copy the full path from file explorer and paste it. This solution works for me.

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/xyz/FaceDetect/faceId/OpenCV-Python-Series-master/src/cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
```