# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in java and opencv 3.0 and what does it mean?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to run a code in java and when I run this code, it throws the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp, line 1634
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1634: error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale
]
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(CascadeClassifier.java:103)
    at FaceDetector.main(FaceDetector.java:30)
```

My source code is the following:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class FaceDetector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

       CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
        //CascadeClassifier cascade1 = new CascadeClassifier("C:/OpenCV/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        //CascadeClassifier cascade1 = new CascadeClassifier("C:/OpenCV/opencv/sources/data/lbpcascade/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
        //CascadeClassifier cascade1=new CascadeClassifier();
        //cascade1.load("C:/opencv2.4.9/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
       faceDetector.load("C:/opencv2.4.9/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        System.out.println("step1");
        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(FaceDetector.class.getResource("anuj.jpg").getPath());
        System.out.println("step2");
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        System.out.println("step3");
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);
        System.out.println("step4");
        try {
            System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("ERROR IS HERE");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        String filename = "ouput.png";
        System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, image);
    }
}
```

Please tell me what is my mistake. I am not able to solve this. I also tried many variations in the code but it does not work.

Comment: Duplicate of [opencv-3-0-0-facedetect-sample-fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344741/opencv-3-0-0-facedetect-sample-fails)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the classifier is not being loaded properly from file.

Please ensure that faceDetector.load() returns true, otherwise the file is not being read.

Comment: so then please make your answer clear enough by answer too how to "ensure that faceDetector.load() returns true"

Answer (score 3):

This was posted 5 months ago, but for the sake of people who are still going to be faced with this challenge after trying all proposed solutions, there is another possibility which I found out after facing same challenge. If there are spaces in the URL returned by `getPath()`, the spaces are returned as `"%20"`.

For example:
`/C:/Users/Ayomide.Johnson/Documents/NetBeansProjects/OpenCV%20Test%20Project/build/classes/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`
You need to change the `"%20"` back to spaces.

My tweek was:
`FaceDetector.class.getResource("x.JPG").getPath().substring(1).replace("%20", " ")` and it worked!

Note: The `substring(1)` is to remove the initial `"/"` in the path. If you do not need that call, you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with the same problem. Indicating the directory of the **haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml** file worked fine for me. You may try it too.

```
package faceDetection;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetection
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);


        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier();
        faceDetector.load("D:\\OpenCv\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        System.out.println ( "Working" );
        // Input image
        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("E:\\input.jpg");

        // Detecting faces
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        // Creating a rectangular box showing faces detected
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray())
        {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
             new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                                           new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        // Saving the output image
        String filename = "Ouput.jpg";
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("E:\\"+filename, image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\\opencv2.4.9\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
```

Use double slash when you give path in windows.

Comment: You can also use a single "normal" slash, even on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Adding convert-buffered-image to mat type variable fixes the problem.

```
package facedetect;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetector {
    // https://blog.openshift.com/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers/
    // make user library and add it to project

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/hayanchoi/scene1.png"));
        detectFace(image);
    }

    private static Mat convertBufImg2Mat(BufferedImage image) {
        DataBufferByte s;
        byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        mat.put(0, 0, data);
        return mat;
    }

    private static int detectFace(BufferedImage image) {

        System.out.println("step0: Running FaceDetector");
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(
                FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
        if (!faceDetector.load("E:/hayanchoi/FaceDetectionTest/bin/facedetect/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")) {
            return -1;
        }

        System.out.println("step1: convert bufferedimage to mat type");
        Mat matImage = convertBufImg2Mat(image);


        System.out.print("step2: detect face- ");
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(matImage, faceDetections);
        System.out.println(String.format(" %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

        System.out.println("step3: write faces");
        String filename = "/0_research/" + "ouput.png";
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            writeFrame(filename, matImage, rect);
        }
        return faceDetections.toArray().length;
    }

    private static BufferedImage cropImage(BufferedImage src, Rect rect) {
        BufferedImage dest = src.getSubimage(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        return dest;
    }

    public static void writeFrame(String filename, Mat mat, Rect rect) {

        byte[] data = new byte[mat.rows() * mat.cols() * (int) (mat.elemSize())];
        mat.get(0, 0, data);
        if (mat.channels() == 3) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
                byte temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[i + 2];
                data[i + 2] = temp;
            }
        }
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        image.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, mat.cols(), mat.rows(), data);
        BufferedImage frame = cropImage(image, rect);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File(filename + ".png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }


}
```

Comment: Actually i didn't make the function writeframe yet, please see the upper side of the code;0 sorry

Answer (score 0):

Java didn't work with `getResoure("...").getPath()` 
So change all lines have that function to absolute path , example :`"C:/Users/USER/workspace/SmallTest/bin/face.jpg"`
I just have resolved it.
Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

First of all in this case you should check if `CascadeClassifier` has properly loaded the specified XML resource.
There are 2 ways of doing this: either check if the `load()` method returns true. Another way (e.g. if you didn't use this method just specifying the necessary resource in the constructor) is to use `empty()` method to ensure classifier has been loaded properly.